# BigQuery - How to find BitCoin input addresses for a specific output address

Tags: google-bigquery

BigQuery Public Data Set: Crypto_Bitcoin

I've been trying to identify all the unique input (sender) addresses that are sending Bitcoins to a specific address (e.g. XXX). Despite feeling this to be a straightforward query based on the Database Schema, I am getting errors despite countless attempts. Could anyone please help identify what's the issue here:

`SELECT DISTINCT inputs.addresses FROM bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions as transactions, transactions.inputs as inputs WHERE outputs.addresses = "XXX"`

Thanks

[Data Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crwj5.png)

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I am getting this "Cannot access field addresses on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, script_asm STRING, script_hex STRING, ...>> at [4:15]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Try below

```
SELECT DISTINCT input_address
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions` AS transactions, 
  transactions.inputs AS input, input.addresses AS input_address,
  transactions.outputs AS output, output.addresses AS output_address
WHERE output_address = "XXX"
```